# Different options on btrfs subvolumes

Tags: linux, compression, btrfs, disk-volume

I'm using kernel 3.0 and was wondering if btrfs supports / is planning to support different options on different subvolumes.
For example I'd like to turn compression on for /usr, /lib, ..., but not for the faster changing directories like /home and not for /boot since it's not supported by grub yet.

Would this work as described? Or is `compress` impossible in that configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It (currently) doesn't work. These features are planned but there is no schedule when this feature will be implemented. There are other tasks that have higher priority. But to get a better answer you should join the BTRFS mailing list or ask Chris or Josef on IRC (#btrfs).