# Listed btrfs mount options are not expected how I did

Tags: mount, btrfs, debian-buster

In my /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=... / btrfs   subvol=@,defaults,relatime,space_cache,autodefrag 0 1
UUID=... /media/fs.cave btrfs subvolid=5,defaults,relatime,space_cache,autodefrag 0 0
UUID=... /var/lib/libvirt/images btrfs nodefaults,subvol=vm.images,relatime,space_cache,nodatacow 0 0
```

The output of "mount" is:

```
/dev/sda5 on /var/lib/libvirt/images type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,autodefrag,subvolid=268,subvol=/vm.images)
```

I do not expect the option "autodefrag" and I am missing the option "nodatacow".

Is there another possability to find out the active options?

OS: debian buster with kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64 and 5.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64

Comment: After installing the kernel 5.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64: same behaviour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different options on btrfs subvolumes](https://serverfault.com/questions/328188/different-options-on-btrfs-subvolumes)

Comment: The post is related to kernel 3. I am using kernel 5.

Comment: see https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide "Each of these subvolumes/mountpoints can be mounted with some options being different."

Comment: I had it read before I wrote. What's your q-n. Subvolumes do share some mount options and there's some Work-in-Progress in regards, so things my change in recent kernels. Anyways and again — what's your q-n?

Comment: I want to know, whether the option "nodatadow" is active for /var/lib/libvirt/images. It is not listed in the mount command (without options)

Comment: I had a similar issue, I'm thinking that the BTRFS option directly on my swap file is how this author might have got around this option, as swapfiles should have `compress=no` https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/pop-os-btrfs/#commento-login-box-container

Answer (score 0):

Better than mounting with attributes: use the attributes of a subdirectory:

```
chattr -RV C /var/lib/libvirt/images
```

see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html

> If the 'C' flag is set on a directory, it will have no effect on the directory, but new files created in that directory will have the No_COW attribute set.

This attribute can be retrieved:

```
lsattr -R /var/lib/libvirt/images
```

- only non directory files will have the attribute
- only files created/changed after the "chattr" command have the attribute